# Tricky Textbox with imacros

Tags: captcha, imacros

i have a little tricky `Captcha` Textbox i want to fill with `iMacros`. The Textbox hax the following Code:

```
<input data-prevent-submit="false" class="captcha_input form-element form-element-textfield textfield js-component" value="" name="chapter:chapter_body:fieldset:fieldset_body:captchaTextFieldItem:captchaText FieldItem_body:captchaTextField" id="ide7" placeholder="Zeichen aus Bild eingeben" data-component="Textfield" type="text">
```

I can fill the Form with `imacros` and submit, but it doesn't work. Seems that the Textbox doesn't recognises my Input. Maybe i have to Focus the box first and than fill it up.

My `iMacros` Code is simple like this:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:id* ATTR=ID:ide7 CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:ide3 ATTR=ID:ide4
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Cheers, Chris

Heres the Website Code:

```
<div class="layer-body">


<div class="captcha">
<form id="idf5" method="post" action="./popImap;jsessionid=7694A5FB6B8DC9BBD48C31C42BFCE41A-n1.bs54a?2-1.IFormSubmitListener-topLevelContainer-dialog-root~container-container-form" class="m-form"><div style="width:0px;height:0px;position:absolute;left:-100px;top:-100px;overflow:hidden"><input name="idf5_hf_0" id="idf5_hf_0" type="hidden"></div><div style="width:0px;height:0px;position:absolute;left:-100px;top:-100px;overflow:hidden"><input autocomplete="off" type="text"><input name="chapter:chapter_body:bottomButtons:container:bottomButtons_body:ok" onclick=" var b=document.getElementById('idf6'); if (b!=null&amp;&amp;b.onclick!=null&amp;&amp;typeof(b.onclick) != 'undefined') {  var r = Wicket.bind(b.onclick, b)(); if (r != false) b.click(); } else { b.click(); };  return false;" type="submit"></div>
<div class="form-chapter">

<h4 class="headline-layout4 headline">Sicherheitsabfrage</h4>

<p class="paragraph">Helfen Sie uns Spam zu bekämpfen! Bitte geben Sie den angezeigten Code ein.</p>
<div id="idf7" style="display:none"></div>
<fieldset class="m-form-fieldset m-form-fieldset-styled-variant-b">
<div class="m-form-fieldset-styled_wrapper">

<div class="captcha_image-container">
<span class="captcha_spinner"></span>
<img class="captcha_image" id="idf8" src="./popImap;jsessionid=7694A5FB6B8DC9BBD48C31C42BFCE41A-n1.bs54a?2-IResourceListener-topLevelContainer-dialog-root~container-container-form-chapter-chapter_body-fieldset-fieldset_body-captchaImage&amp;antiCache=1457521123954">
</div>
<div class="m-form-item">

<div class="m-form-item_container">

<input data-prevent-submit="false" class="captcha_input form-element form-element-textfield textfield js-component" value="" name="chapter:chapter_body:fieldset:fieldset_body:captchaTextFieldItem:captchaTextFieldItem_body:captchaTextField" id="idf9" placeholder="Zeichen aus Bild eingeben" data-component="Textfield" type="text">
<a id="idf3" href="javascript:;" class="icon-link js-component" data-component="IconLink" icon="refresh">
<i class="m-icon icon-link_icon"></i>
</a>

</div>
</div>

</div>
</fieldset>
    <p class="paragraph">Mit dieser Maßnahme schützen wir vor ungewollten Manipulationen</p>

<div class="m-button-container m-button-container-right">

<button  name="chapter:chapter_body:bottomButtons:container:bottomButtons_body:cancel" id="idf4" value="Abbrechen" type="button" class="button-size-normal m-button button-transparent js-component button-secondary layer-close" data-component="Button">
Abbrechen


    </button>
    <button name="chapter:chapter_body:bottomButtons:container:bottomButtons_body:ok" id="idf6" value="Speichern" class="button-size-normal m-button button-cta js-component" data-component="Button">
Speichern


</button>

</div>


</div> 
</form>
</div>

</div>
```

And here the recorded Macro:

```
    URL GOTO=https://navigator.web.de/?sid=8266e33e4a68f4dc2245fcc7e22063633d603457ed697b8c7aa7cf77306e5e1462f3096157b0b1bc031b669d19bc9df1&tz=1#mail
    FRAME NAME="mail"
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:id89 ATTR=ID:id8a
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:ide3 ATTR=ID:ide7 CONTENT=Testinput
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:ide3 ATTR=ID:ide4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Thanks for your help!

i changed the recording mode and finaly solved it with:

```
FRAME NAME="mail"
CLICK X=365 Y=317
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:id* ATTR=ID:id* CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
wait seconds=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:ide3 ATTR=ID:ide4
```

before TAG TYPE

easy ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Select the XPATH of that text field and try the below code.

```
URL GOTO=https://navigator.web.de/?sid=8266e33e4a68f4dc2245fcc7e22063633d603457ed697b8c7aa7cf77306e5e1462f3096157b0b1bc031b669d19bc9df1&tz=1#mail FRAME NAME="mail"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:id89 ATTR=ID:id8a 
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS XPATH="//select[@id="billing:country_id"]" CHARS={{!VAR1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:ide3 ATTR=ID:ide4
```

Comment: Thanks. But i m not really sure what i have to put after the XPATH:"..." to identify the Form.

Comment: I'm not clear with your question.. You are already into the form right?... the above mentioned code will focus on the field first and then enter the data which is in "VAR1".. probably you can share the form URL, I will chk and let you know

Comment: no, i think thats the Problem. Im not allready in the Form. My Problem is to select the Form. Im not sure how to do that. Sharing is difficult because its in a logged in area.

Comment: You just Record your entire actions, from the launching of your Form, and send me the script.. I will check and let you know

Comment: Thanks in advance. i have posted it in the main Post above,

Comment: I edited the script, this is how you need to use the tag. In order to find the XPATH of that text field, in the Firefox browser, install Firebug plugin, and then install the Firepath plugin, and then follow the steps mentioned in the below URL, []http://selenium-by-arun.blogspot.in/2012/11/6-how-to-use-firepath.html]

once you identify the XPATH of the textfield replace it in the above mentioned code

Comment: Thanks for editing and the tip with Firepath. I tried it as you mentioned. but get the following error in iMacros: RuntimeError: Can not locate element specified by xpath ".//*[@id='ide7']", line 3 (Error code: -921)